# The identifer FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE is undeclared

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using libmpsse_spi.h for SPI communication through FT2232H. When I use this I get an error in the following program on the line:

> FTDI_API FT_STATUS SPI_GetChannelInfo(uint32 index,
>   FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE *chanInfo);

This line is under Function Declaration.

The error says that the identifier **FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE** is undefined. What can be the way to resolve this issue?

I searched in FTD2XX.H (which is the only include as can be seen in the program), but FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE is not defined there.

Operating System: Windows XP
MS VC 2010

**Note: I am including this library libmpsse_spi.h  in a .cpp file.  The author has provided a sample code to demonstrate the usage of the library, but he is calling this in a .c file.**

```
/*!
 * \file libMPSSE_spi.h
 *
 * \author FTDI
 * \date 20110527
 *
 * Copyright © 2011 Future Technology Devices International Limited
 * Company Confidential
 *
 * Project: libMPSSE
 * Module: SPI
 *
 * Rivision History:
 * 0.1 - initial version
 * 0.2 - 20110708 - added FT_ReadGPIO, FT_WriteGPIO & SPI_ChangeCS
 * 0.3 - 20111025 - modified for supporting 64bit linux
 */

#ifndef LIBMPSSE_SPI_H
#define LIBMPSSE_SPI_H

#include "FTD2XX.H"


/******************************************************************************/
/*                              Macro defines                                 */
/******************************************************************************/

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define FTDI_API extern "C"
#else
#define FTDI_API
#endif

/* Bit defination of the transferOptions parameter in SPI_Read, SPI_Write & SPI_Transfer  */

/* transferOptions-Bit0: If this bit is 0 then it means that the transfer size provided is in bytes */
#define SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BYTES          0x00000000
/* transferOptions-Bit0: If this bit is 1 then it means that the transfer size provided is in bytes */
#define SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_SIZE_IN_BITS           0x00000001
/* transferOptions-Bit1: if BIT1 is 1 then CHIP_SELECT line will be enables at start of transfer */
#define SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_ENABLE      0x00000002
/* transferOptions-Bit2: if BIT2 is 1 then CHIP_SELECT line will be disabled at end of transfer */
#define SPI_TRANSFER_OPTIONS_CHIPSELECT_DISABLE     0x00000004




/* Bit defination of the Options member of configOptions structure*/
#define SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_MODE_MASK     0x00000003
#define SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_MODE0         0x00000000
#define SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_MODE1         0x00000001
#define SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_MODE2         0x00000002
#define SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_MODE3         0x00000003

#define SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_MASK           0x0000001C      /*111 00*/
#define SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_DBUS3      0x00000000      /*000 00*/
#define SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_DBUS4      0x00000004      /*001 00*/
#define SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_DBUS5      0x00000008      /*010 00*/
#define SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_DBUS6      0x0000000C      /*011 00*/
#define SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_DBUS7      0x00000010      /*100 00*/

#define SPI_CONFIG_OPTION_CS_ACTIVELOW  0x00000020


/******************************************************************************/
/*                              Type defines                                  */
/******************************************************************************/

typedef unsigned char   uint8;
typedef unsigned short  uint16;
typedef unsigned long long uint64;

typedef signed char   int8;
typedef signed short  int16;
typedef signed long long int64;

#ifndef _MSC_VER
typedef unsigned char   bool;
#endif

#ifdef __x86_64__  
/*20111025: 64bit linux doesn't work is uint32 is unsigned long*/
    typedef unsigned int   uint32;
    typedef signed int   int32;
#else
    typedef unsigned long   uint32;
    typedef signed long   int32;
#endif

typedef enum I2C_ClockRate_t{
    I2C_CLOCK_STANDARD_MODE = 100000,                           // 100kb/sec
    I2C_CLOCK_FAST_MODE = 400000,                               // 400kb/sec
    I2C_CLOCK_FAST_MODE_PLUS = 1000000,                         // 1000kb/sec
    I2C_CLOCK_HIGH_SPEED_MODE = 3400000                         // 3.4Mb/sec
}I2C_CLOCKRATE;

typedef struct ChannelConfig_t
{
    uint32  ClockRate; 

    uint8   LatencyTimer; 

    uint32  configOptions;  /*This member provides a way to enable/disable features
    specific to the protocol that are implemented in the chip
    BIT1-0=CPOL-CPHA:   00 - MODE0 - data captured on rising edge, propagated on falling
                        01 - MODE1 - data captured on falling edge, propagated on rising
                        10 - MODE2 - data captured on falling edge, propagated on rising
                        11 - MODE3 - data captured on rising edge, propagated on falling
    BIT4-BIT2: 000 - A/B/C/D_DBUS3=ChipSelect
             : 001 - A/B/C/D_DBUS4=ChipSelect
             : 010 - A/B/C/D_DBUS5=ChipSelect
             : 011 - A/B/C/D_DBUS6=ChipSelect
             : 100 - A/B/C/D_DBUS7=ChipSelect
    BIT5: ChipSelect is active high if this bit is 0
    BIT6 -BIT31     : Reserved
    */

    uint32      Pin;/*BIT7   -BIT0:   Initial direction of the pins */
                    /*BIT15 -BIT8:   Initial values of the pins     */
                    /*BIT23 -BIT16: Final direction of the pins     */
                    /*BIT31 -BIT24: Final values of the pins        */
    uint16      reserved;
}ChannelConfig;


/******************************************************************************/
/*                              External variables                            */
/******************************************************************************/





/******************************************************************************/
/*                              Function declarations                         */
/******************************************************************************/
FTDI_API FT_STATUS SPI_GetNumChannels(uint32 *numChannels);
FTDI_API FT_STATUS SPI_GetChannelInfo(uint32 index, FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE *chanInfo);
FTDI_API FT_STATUS SPI_OpenChannel(uint32 index, FT_HANDLE *handle);
FTDI_API FT_STATUS SPI_InitChannel(FT_HANDLE handle, ChannelConfig *config);
FTDI_API FT_STATUS SPI_CloseChannel(FT_HANDLE handle);
FTDI_API FT_STATUS SPI_Read(FT_HANDLE handle, uint8 *buffer, 
    uint32 sizeToTransfer, uint32 *sizeTransfered, uint32 options);
FTDI_API FT_STATUS SPI_Write(FT_HANDLE handle, uint8 *buffer, 
    uint32 sizeToTransfer, uint32 *sizeTransfered, uint32 options);
FTDI_API FT_STATUS SPI_ReadWrite(FT_HANDLE handle, uint8 *inBuffer, 
    uint8 *outBuffer, uint32 sizeToTransfer, uint32 *sizeTransferred, 
    uint32 transferOptions);
FTDI_API FT_STATUS SPI_IsBusy(FT_HANDLE handle, bool *state);
FTDI_API void Init_libMPSSE(void);
FTDI_API void Cleanup_libMPSSE(void);
FTDI_API FT_STATUS SPI_ChangeCS(FT_HANDLE handle, uint32 configOptions);
FTDI_API FT_STATUS FT_WriteGPIO(FT_HANDLE handle, uint8 dir, uint8 value);
FTDI_API FT_STATUS FT_ReadGPIO(FT_HANDLE handle,uint8 *value);



/******************************************************************************/


#endif  /*LIBMPSSE_SPI_H*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should download D2XX driver and use header ftd2xx.h from the